# When to create statistics?

Tags: performance, database-design

In SQL Server, when to create statistics only on a table column instead of index and when create to index (which creates statistics as well automatically)?

Comment: columns being used in JOIN, WHERE, ORDER BY, or GROUP clauses are good candidates

Comment: I mean when comparatively better to add statistics than index. In joins etc index is also candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statistics are useful when only telling the distribution/cardinality pattern of data to SQL engine can help it in devising better execution plan where as index specifically is the need when telling the data pattern is not enough and special data access structure (i.e. b-tree ) is required to reduce data scans and scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options#auto_create_statistics) when the automatic create statistics option, `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` is `ON`:

> The query optimizer creates statistics on single columns in query
>   predicates, as necessary, to improve query plans and query
>   performance. These single-column statistics are created when the query
>   optimizer compiles queries.

Hence you need to create statistics manually in the following cases at least:

- `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` is `OFF`
- multi-column statistics is required
- filtered statistics is required

Index and statistics are not comparable. In general, index is used to access data the more efficient way than a table scan. Statistics is required for optimizer to estimate the number of returned rows.

Comment: "multi-column statistics is required
filtered statistics is required"Why statistics and not index?

Comment: @AhmedMustafa for example, the index may be useless but takes a significant disk space and/or makes updates slower whereas the statistics doesn't